# The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context when creating new xaml file

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have searched for an answer to this question for a while so I hope that my instance can be solved. I created a new Xamarin.Forms shared projects in visual studio 2015 community. I created a new xaml file and name it **LoginPage** and placed it in a folder named Pages in the shared app project. After adding the Xamarin.Forms namespace for it to recognize **Page** and removing **this.** before **InitializeComponent** I have this:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BeneFit.Pages
{

    public sealed partial class LoginPage : Page
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
        InitializeComponent(); //This has the red squiggly
        }
    }
}
```

The Xaml file here has not been changed at all:

```
<Page
    x:Class="BeneFit.Pages.LoginPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BeneFit.Pages"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

One thing I have notice a lot is that the build action needs to be **Page** which I made sure of in this case. Also the suggested quick fix was to add this:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

which doesnt really solve the issue because I know I should have to do it. Any help or suggestions would be huge, ive been trying to deal with this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new control or page in XAML, a hidden partial class file is also generated behind the scenes, this holds your `InitializeComponent()` method. In the case of a page called `LoginPage` the generated code behind will be called `LoginPage.g.i.cs`, and it should reside in the folder structures under the `obj` folder.

Your XAML line

```
xmlns:local="using:BeneFit.Pages"
```

does look a bit funky, I would change that to

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BeneFit.Pages"
```

Comment: Ok I found `LoginPage.g.cs` which was the only other file. I still dont understand why the InitializeComponent() method is still doesnt exist. Im new to c# so Im still learning these concepts

Comment: @DallasPhillips this particular issue usually happens if you move a file on the filesystem or if you change a namespace after you've created the file.

Comment: I never moved/renamed the files. The code i showed was from new files. Should i delete them and create new ones.

Comment: @Dallas you can't go wrong with re-creating them. Also check that your /obj folder isn't under source control or read only, and make sure you test that namespace change I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Go to each project folder (shared, .Android, .ios etc) and delete obj and bin folders (this will remove the hidden partial .g file)

Rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Three checks to fulfill:

1 - Latest Xamarin Forms nuget installed same versions for all platforms

2 - For page.Xaml properties are :

```
   Build Action: Embedded Resource
   Copy to output dir: Do not copy
   Custom tool (most common error when created page manually): MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml
```

For page.cs properties are:

```
Build action: Compile
Copy to output dir: Do not copy
```

3 - Right-click project - Unload project, then reload project.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like UWP XAML not Xamarin Forms XAML.

Are you creating the wrong new thing?

You should be creating a new Xamarin.Forms Content Page

[image]